# How to create these SQL tables

Tags: sql

I have a table for 'Parts':

- ID (PK)
- name
- detail

so an example Parts Table:

- 1 "book" "A red book"
- 2 "desk" "A wood desk"
- 3 "table" "A cheap table"

I want to make 'groups' of these parts so for example a 'normal' group would be a book and table where an 'extra' group would be a book and desk.

You'd be able to do "SELECT * FROM 'groups' WHERE name='normal'". How would I accomplish this?

Hopefully I explained this good enough (Google searches for 'groups' fails due to the SQL group by keyword)

Comment: Please edit: Do you mean WHERE group_name='normal'"?

Comment: You cannot do it like that exactly. You would need to create another table called Groups. It would contain two columns: ID, and Name. You then add two rows this table for normal and extra. You would added a new column to Parts called Group_ID. For each part in Parts, you put the populate its Group_ID from ID in Groups. To select 'normal' items, you do: SELECT * FROM Parts JOIN Groups ON Parts.Group_ID = Groups.ID WHERE Groups.Name = 'normal'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a second table which defines the groups and which items belong to it.

So, in this case, you'd want a table named "Groups" with attributes

- GroupName (PK)
- ItemID (PK) (Foreign Key from Parts)

(The Foreign Key constraint listed above is not strictly necessary, but the primary key
does definitely have to be both GroupName and ItemID.  If it is just one or the other, the table will not work right.)

And then the entries would be

- "normal" 1
- "normal" 3
- "extra" 1
- "extra" 2

Then you would want to use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Groups, Parts WHERE Groups.ItemID = Parts.ID
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (Groups JOIN Parts ON Groups.ItemID = Parts.ID)
```